# MySQL convert many-to-many table into one-to-one

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a table which is created by joining 2 tables and now the two columns looks like having a `many-to-many` relationship. I want to convert this to a `one-to-one` relationship meaning, values in both the columns has to be `unique`.  Here is a sample setting;

```
create table Test(id1 integer, id2 integer);
insert into Test(id1, id2) values(1, 10);
insert into Test(id1, id2) values(1, 20);
insert into Test(id1, id2) values(2, 10);
insert into Test(id1, id2) values(2, 20);
select * from Test;
```

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |

I want to convert the above table into something as below;

`tbl1`

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |

**OR**

`tbl2`

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 10 |

How to write a SQL query to convert `test` table to `tbl1` or `tbl2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take out unique values as mentioned in the comments on my other answer.

```
SELECT a.id1, b.id2
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id1) AS RowNum FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id1 FROM test) x
) AS a,
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id2) AS RowNum FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id2 FROM test) x
) AS b
WHERE a.RowNum = b.RowNum
```

Let me know if there is something I misunderstood.

Comment: Great @MrApnea. I get what you have done, its all about getting your logic right ya. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. To force the table to have unique columns you can just add a unique index on the table. (Feel free to change to better name on the index).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index_name_1 ON test(id1);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index_name_2 ON test(id2);
```

Then the indexes will not allow any duplicates.
(There can't be any duplicates when you create the indexes above.)

But....if you have full control over the database it seems a bit strange to have this type of table if there are only 1 to 1 relations. Then you could just add a fields on the two main tables instead.

If the ids are coming from the tables 'Table1' and 'Table2' you can have a field in Table1 which are called table2_id and pointing to the row in table2. And in the Table2 you could have a field called table1_id and that would point to table1. Then you could just skip this table and all searches would be faster. But of course there might be a reason this is not possible. Just wanted to mention it anyways...

Comment: thanks for your comment. Please note that I am not trying to stop the duplicates in the `test` table for future  but I want to clean this data which is already I have. 
Yes as you mentioned, we are going to create table2_id so we can avoid this issue in the future. but before that I have to create that mapping using the data already in the tables.

Comment: Ok. Well let us know if you need more assistance and if my answer works for you then please accept it or give us more info what is missing and we might be able to help with the missing part.

Comment: Sorry @MrApnea as I mentioned this answer wouldn't help to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok. So am I understanding you correct that you want to throw away connections and just save one connection so that the table will have unique values? And it does not matter which value is saved as long as they all are unique after the query?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the question at first, so this is my new answer.
As I understand it you want to remove rows so the only rows left are unique and it does not matter which rows are deleted? If so, this solution will work:

```
DELETE test
FROM test
JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT t.id1, t.id2, (SELECT MAX(id2) FROM test WHERE id1 = t.id1) AS maxId2
            from test t
        ) AS r
    WHERE r.id2 != maxId2
) d
 ON d.id1 = test.id1 AND d.id2 = test.id2;
```

This query will delete all rows except the ones with the highest id2.
Please test it and make a backup before running it, I have of course tested it on my side but still.

Comment: Thanks for your try but unfortunately it gives;
| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1   | 20  |
| 2   | 20  |

where as I dont want any duplicates in column `id2`.

Comment: Ok. I think that I start to get what you want. But what if you have the data from your question and also the data (id1=3, id2=20). What would you want then? Then there is no way of keeping them unique without throwing some data away? Or are you sure that the data can be unique?

Comment: There won't be a case such as `data(id1=3, id2=20)` in isolation. In that case the data will have 9 rows. Then table would look like `data(id1 = (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3) , id2 = (10,20,30),(10,20,30),(10,20,30) `.  Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases do not recommend/allow many to many relationships by design. However, for this specific requirement, following code should get closer to what you want. Code is on a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31cf65e305ee9cfda20a92d163401547)

```
create table tb11(id1 integer, id2 integer);
create table tb12(id1 integer, id2 integer);

INSERT INTO tb11  
SELECT id1, id2 FROM  
(SELECT
    id1,
    id2,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id2 ORDER BY id1 ASC) as rnk
FROM
    Test) t1 where t1.rnk = 1;

INSERT INTO tb12  
SELECT id1, id2 FROM  
(SELECT
    id1,
    id2,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id2 ORDER BY id1 ASC) as rnk
FROM
    Test) t2  where t2.rnk = 2;

SELECT * FROM tb11;
SELECT * FROM tb12;
```